# Request for Retail Pricing Data on Print-On-Demand Ecommerce Products

Tags: data-request, business

I am looking for an open data set(s) to benchmark pricing for print-on-demand products sold through online e-commerce stores and marketplaces like custom clothing, home goods, phone cases, accessories, wall art, etc.

Ideally the data would include:

- Final retail pricing for print-on-demand products segmented by physical product type and by print-on-demand vendor. While a full data set would be great, range and distribution would work.
- An indicator if shipping is included in the price
- Benchmark pricing trends over time would be nice

This is intended for competitive intelligence and price benchmarking for a print-on-demand e-commerce businesses. I intent to turn the data into a Tableau Public dashboard to filter by product and vendor to allow people to see price ranges and distributions by product and vendor.

I'm looking for aggregated data sources that can show generalized pricing behavior specifically for print-on-demand goods, rather than an individual store or product pricing data. Please let me know if you are aware of any data set(s) or other resources that could lead to aggregated pricing statistics on print-on-demand e-commerce products segmented as described.

Thank you!